# How to read the weight from a USB Scale

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a `USB` weighing scale that I'm trying to import the reading into an HTML form, either via `Ajax/Js` and/or Server side `VBScript` (classic asp).

Does anyone have any suggestions where I should begin my search?

Comment: Does the scale look like a standard USB HID device that "types" a weight as if it were a keyboard? Or is it more complicated?

Comment: It's a stamps.com scale, you just put the package on it and the software reads it.. I'm assuming it should be the same type of scale as the others, but there's no keyboard or nothing, its auto.

Comment: Is HTML your best option here, don't you think something a bit more low level would be better?

Comment: @JasperKennis It's got to be in a web form. I can use ajax if necessary.

Comment: Well, uh, let me try to rephrase my earlier question a little. If you have `notepad.exe` or `gvim` open, will the scale happily "type" numbers into the interface? Or do you have to run a driver and query an API to read the values?

Comment: @sarnold no it will not, it is specifically for Stamps.com application, plug and play, and it only works in the application by pressing the 'weigh' button it reads whats on the scale right there and puts it in the app.

Comment: @sarnold I actually found the drivers online, but I still dont understand how to read it from an application.

Comment: Ah, if you need drivers then you'll need to write a native application that can serve as a bridge to your HTML forms. Pity.

Comment: @sarnold Can it be written in classic ASP / VBScript?  I can use ajax to get it in the web form.

Comment: No. JavaScript (and VBScript) don't have the necessary hardware access. ASP is on the wrong end of the network to do anything at all.

Comment: @duskwuff How about server side VBscript?

Comment: Server side VBScript is doubly an abomination. It is not spoken of in polite company. Also, it's on the wrong end of the network just like ASP would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by looking at the documentations that comes with the device. You might need some drivers that actually read the value for you and after that you get to pass it arouond

Comment: I found the drivers online, what's next? How do I get the application to read it?

Comment: Does windows detect your device and ask for drivers? I think this is a hardware issue and not for StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

**Conceptual Error.**

The browser is software **installed** on the computer. Javascript is merely scripting that runs inside the browser. Javascript cannot access anything that the browser does not reveal to it.

If a browser provided Javascript with access to randomly connected hardware, a simple Web page could copy your hard drive, start up your web cam, or melt down a nuke plant.